# String concatenation of xml using oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to string concatenate xml using below oracle sql query. its throwing error when there are invalid characters in the data. Kindly suggest if any improvement can be done.

```
SELECT
    'Outstanding Conditions:' || outstanding_conditions "OUTSTANDING_CONDITIONS"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            rtrim(
                XMLAGG(xmlelement(
                                 e,
                                 chr(13)
                                 || rownum
                                 || '. '
                                 || replace(
                                           replace(
                                                  condition_desc,
                                                  'PBK''S',
                                                  'PBK'
                                           ),
                                           'PBK',
                                          'PBK'
                                    )
                       ).extract('//text()')
                    ORDER BY
                        application_id
                ).getclobval()
            ) "OUTSTANDING_CONDITIONS"
        FROM
            tbl_assessment_cond
        WHERE
            condition_status = 'U'
            AND application_id = 'Z01234567'
            AND instr(
                '~S~', '~'
                   || is_acceptance
                   || '~'
            ) > 0
    )
WHERE
    outstanding_conditions IS NOT NULL;
```

> Error:
> ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
> ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
> LPX-00216: invalid character 160 (0xA0)
> Error at line 2
> 31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
> *Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
> *Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: check out dbms_xmlgen.convert and/or htf.escape_sc to escape data in XML

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you want to solve. Oracle 12+ supports `varchar2` length [up to 32k bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321) so you may try to use `listagg` (with `on overflow truncate` if  applicable) instead of xml building and subsequent parsing